# How to compile in two steps using SCons?

Tags: c, scons

I will like to compile files in the following steps using SCons:

.c -> .asm(assembly file) -> .o

I tried to define different builders for this.

I managed to do something like:  .asm -> .o and .c -> .o

I don't know how to make SCons aware of the .asm files generated from .c files and then to use the object builder.

Is there any possibility to use current SCons implementation for this ?

**EDIT:** This is what I tried :

-> To define two builders: Builder 1 (c_to_asm) is intended to do .c -> .asm step
                           Builder 2 (asm_to_o) is intended to do .asm -> .o . After these two builders are executed for all the files defined in my SConscript I expect the Program builder to create the final executable.

```
SCons.Tool.createProgBuilder(env)

c_to_asm = SCons.Builder.Builder(action = {},
                                 emitter = {}, 
                                 prefix = '', 
                                 suffix = '.asm',
                                 src_builder = '',
                                 source_scanner = '',
                                 single_source = 1)
c_to_asm_action = SCons.Action.Action('c to asm command line', 'Executing .c to .asm builder')

c_to_asm.add_action('.c', c_to_asm_action)


asm_to_o = SCons.Builder.Builder(action = {},
                                 emitter = {},
                                 prefix = '',
                                 suffix = '.o',
                                 src_builder = ['CTOASM'],
                                 source_scanner = '',
                                 single_source = 1)

asm_to_o_action = SCons.Action.Action('asm to o command line', 'Executing .asm to .o builder...')
asm_to_o.add_action('.asm', asm_to_o_action)





env['BUILDERS']['CTOASM'] = c_to_asm
env['BUILDERS']['Object'] = asm_to_o
```

I see the execution string for each builder but no command is executed.

I don't know how to establish in which order these builders execute actions and how to trigger this builders.

Comment: Please give a little more info about what exactly you've tried so far. How do your Builders look and how do you initialize and call them? What exactly is the error message that you get or which detail problem are you working on at the moment? (e.g.: Do your files get built, but the dependencies aren't correct such that the "clean" run leaves files behind?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a little complicated. From the top of my head I'd try something like this (untested, but hopefully gives you a direction to continue with):

```
import SCons.Action
import SCons.Builder
# Automatically inits "nasm" Tool, if it is in the $PATH
env = Environment()

c_to_asm_action = SCons.Action.Action('c to asm command line', 'Executing .c to .asm builder')
c_to_asm = SCons.Builder.Builder(action = c_to_asm_action,
                                 suffix = '.asm',
                                 single_source = 1)

env['BUILDERS']['CTOASM'] = c_to_asm

# Creates first.asm and second.asm
env.CTOASM(['first.c', 'second.c'])
# Compiles final program, finds the newly created ASM files via Glob
env.Program('foo', Glob('*.asm') + list_of_your_other_sources_and_libs)
```